# The orders of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$- rational points of a fixed abelian variety and MAGMA computation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, magma

Let $A$ be an abelian variety over $\mathbb{F}_p$.
Then of course for every natural number $i$, we have that $\# A(\mathbb{F}_{p^i})$ divides $\# A(\mathbb{F}_{p^{i+1}})$.

But MAGMA says this is false:
Here is my code:

```
P<x> := PolynomialRing((FiniteField(3)));
J := Jacobian(HyperellipticCurve(x^6 - 2 * x^5 + x^4 - 2 * x^3 + 6 * x^2 - 4 * x + 1));
for j in [1..10] do;
    Order(BaseChange(J, FiniteField(3, j)));
end for;
```

And the result is:

19
57
1444
5529
59299
467856
4976347
43264425
394975876
3458495577

What is wrong?

Comment: Perhaps the code is buggy and does not check whether the curve is singular or not! The way you have written your hyperelliptic curve is confusing. Is the curve the same as the one associated with $x^6+x^5+x^4+2*x+1$? Perhaps that curve is singular over $\mathbb{F}_3$.

Comment: @Kapil Thank you for your comment. But Magma says this curve is smooth...

Comment: OK! I missed the point that you were looking at $\mathbb{F}_{p^i}$ and $\mathbb{F}_{p^{i+1}$. as pointed out by Alex J Best! Embarrassing for me too!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\mathbf F_{p^i}$ is only a subfield of $\mathbf F_{p^j}$ when $i |j$ so you only have the divisibility of group orders for $i|j$ not for $j = i+1$.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It's my soooo simple mistake, I'm embarrassed...